# Ansi escape sequences as bytes

Tags: telnet, ansi-escape

Could someone run me through the bytes in the ansi escape sequences... I'm coding with pen and paper at the moment, and all the ansi tutorials list the codes as ESC[....
I need to see the actual bytes in the stream.
Would one of you gurus with unlimited amount of time devoted to retards like me like to exemplify one or two sequences in bytes?
Big thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first Google image hit for "ascii table". You're welcome. Just match the characters in the tutorial with the red characters, and take the corresponding hex value!

[image]

Comment: ASCII control characters are not escape sequences.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: They aren't, but judging by the original post it looked like what he really wanted were the corresponding bytes for names such as "ESC", and this table has them.

Answer (score 1):

Escape is 0x1B and [ is 0x5B, so you want 1B5B.

Comment: As it turned out I didn't.. I don't even remember thinking I should try to remember it...

Answer (score 0):

You may look for ANSI Sequences to color a terminal (maybe telnet?). I only got a Link for it:
[Ansisequences...](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

Comment: Thanks! I almost forgot about this old project of mine! You made me think of it again, and i think i'll tinker with it a bit tomorrow :)