# Hardcoding Ansii escape sequence for echo in batch file

Tags: batch-file, colors, escaping

I'm writin on a batch-file for windows with colored output using ANSII colors like

```
echo <ESC>[1m Some bold text <ESC>[0m
echo <ESC>[1;32m Some bold green text <ESC>[0m
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38617204/7111561) and [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556026/7111561) I know I have to use the ANSII code 27 character for `<ESC>` and I could copy it from the [file the user linked](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011/raw/b710612d6320df7e146508094e84b92b34c77d48/win10colors.cmd).

This is working fine but I'm wondering if there is any option in batch to "hardcode" this sequence using "normal" (readable) characters as you do e.g in bash on linux

```
echo -e "\033[1;32m Red Bold Text \033[0m"
```

On [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php) I found some options how to insert the escape sequence. And I also read one can use

```
cmd /c exit 65
echo %=exitcodeAscii%
```

to print an `A`, but this seems not to work for

```
cmd /c exit 27
echo %=exitcodeAscii%[31m This would be supposed to be red, right?
```

**How can I produce the escape sequence using code in a batchfile instead of inserting it by pressing certain key-combinations?**

Comment: So you want to use the exit code in ascii to produce the color for you?

Comment: I know how to use it to `echo` with a color. What I want to know if there is another way having the escape sequence in the code without having actually the cryptic symbol which cannot be read/version controlled very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own echo-e.bat file [echo -e equivalent in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497133/463115).

Or use a batch function instead.

```
call :echo-e "\x1b[1;31m Red Bold Text \x1b[0m"
exit /b

:echo-e
setlocal
set "arg1=%~1"
set "arg1=%arg1:\x=0x%"
forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(%arg1%"
exit /b
```

Creating a single escape character (27) you can use FORFILES or PROMPT

Like this sample

```
for /F "delims=#" %%a in ('prompt #$E# ^& for %%a in ^(1^) do rem') do set "esc=%%a"
echo %ESC%[1;31m Red Bold Text %ESC%[0m
```

Comment: @Stephan Thanks, I fixed the "red color" to 31, but the second sample works for me, perhaps you have a _invisible_ space behind `%%a`? Now, I changed the `set esc=%%a` to the secure version `set "esc=%%a"`

Comment: @jeb: now it works for me too. No idea, what was wrong before and I can't reproduce `:/`